# showing that polytropic exponent n = 5/3 corresponds to an isentropic process for a monoatomic ideal gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Given an ideal monoatomic gas with $pV = NT$ and $E = \frac{3}{2}NT$ what are the types of processes described by $n = 0, 1, \frac{5}{3}$, where n is the polytropic exponent ($p V ^ n = const.$)?

That's the question I'm given.

N=0 corresponding to isobaric is immediately obvious, as is N=1 being an isothermic process (when $N = const.$).

However, I can not figure out how to see that $n=\kappa=\frac{5}{3}$ corresponds to isentropic. $$pV^\frac{5}{3}=const.=N\,T\,V^\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3}E\,V^\frac{2}{3}=const.$$and the like get's me nowhere.

Can somebody please give me a hint on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

To show that the process is isentropic, you need to show that $dS=0$. Where $S$ denotes entropy.

From the formula of entropy , $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$.

The equation of the process is $PV^{5/3}=\mathrm{constant}.$

Using the [Polytropic specific heat capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process#Polytropic_Specific_Heat_Capacity),
$$C=\frac{3}{2}R\frac{\frac{5}{3}-\frac{5}{3}}{1-\frac{5}{3}}=0$$

Also, $dQ=CdT=0$.

Hence, $dS=0$.

Comment: Ok - so you're saying my question should've been "How do I come up with the specific heat of a polytropic process"?

Comment: Are you not familiar with that formula?

Comment: Not really. At least not with it's derivation. And without deriving it myself, it's basically the same as looking up that n=5/3 corresponds to an isentropic process :P

Comment: @colorfly It can be derived quite easily using the first law of thermodynamics and the relation $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$. I'll leave it to you as an exercise.

Comment: Don't worry, didn't take more than 30 mins. But I don't see how you can do it in less than 2 A4 sheets.
Can you do it without using $c_p - c_v = N$? Coming up with that alone is a bit lengthy.

Comment: You don't need to prove it each time, do you?